# Find all indented text

Tags: vba, ms-word, text-manipulation

I want to find all text in a document that is indented by 8 spaces. The code below should find these lines and select the line for later processing. However, the code finds/selects all the lines unconditionally. What goes wrong?

Do I have to reset the find result after each match? How doing that?

```
Sub findAndSelectIntendedlines()
    Dim matched As Boolean
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .Execute findtext:="^p        ", Forward:=True, Format:=False, Wrap:=wdFindStop
        matched = .Found
     End With
    If matched Then
            Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
            Selection.Find.Parent.Expand Unit:=wdLine
            Selection.Find.Parent.Copy
            'Debug.Print Selection
    Else
         Debug.Print "not matched"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't a new paragraph be 'indented' by a first line ruler margin or more simply with one or more tabs? What is the source of the .docx that uses 8 spaces to start a new paragraph?

Comment: The input is a plain-text file. Changing the problem/question normally isn't the solution/answer?

Comment: Then I would treat it as a text file. You could open it as a stream and look for vbCRLF & Space(8).

Comment: Still your a changing the problem, aka giving solutions for diffrent/altered problems. I import the plain text into word. Subsequently the logtext is to be formatted by a separte color. This enrichted wordtext is subsequentely to be used in word and will be saved as DOCX. I'm looking for a quite basic vba solution in a DOCX word document.

Answer (score 0):

I have adapted some code I use to replace empty spaces. The routine looks for 2 or more blank spaces. I have added some code and commented out a few lines so you can test and see if it meets your requirements.

```
Sub FindAndReplaceEmptySpaces()
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = " {2,}" 'look for 2 or more
        .Replacement.Text = " " 'replace with 1
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        'The following was added to demo the search
        .Execute
        Do While .found
            rng.MoveEnd Word.WdUnits.wdParagraph, Count:=1
            Debug.Print rng.Text
            rng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
            .Execute
        Loop
        'end of demo code
    End With
'The following code is commented out. Remove comments and demo code above
'to return to the automatically removing extra blank spaces
'    rng.Find.Execute Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll
'    rng.Find.ClearFormatting
'    rng.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

End Sub
```

Comment: I get <run-time error "5560" stating the Find What text contains a Pattern Match expression which is not valid. > with your code.

Comment: @olippuner Try replacing the comma with a semicolon - you may be working on a system that uses a semicolon as the list separator...